# getting error with the following query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [PIPE](
ID double,
REV nvarchar(100),
SCHEDULE double 
RATING nvarchar(100) ,
MATERIAL nvarchar(100) ,
MEAS_UNITS nvarchar(100) ,
MANU_FACT nvarchar(100) ,
EC_CLASS_NAME nvarchar(100) ,
WEIGHT_DRY double ,
END_COND_1 nvarchar(100) ,
PIPE_OD_M double ,
PIPE_OD_R double ,
END_COND_2 nvarchar(100) ,
RUN_SIZE double ,
MAIN_SIZE double ,
MAT_GRADE nvarchar(100) ,
SHORT_DESC nvarchar(100) ,
LONG_DESCR nvarchar(100) ,
WALL_THICKNESS_1 double ,
PIECE_MARK nvarchar(100));
```

I am getting the following error please suggest "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `double` datatype in SQL Server, you need to use either `float` or `real` if you want approximate numbers.  Also you are missing a comma between `schedule` and `rating`:

```
CREATE TABLE [PIPE](
  ID float,
  REV nvarchar(100),
  SCHEDULE float,
  RATING nvarchar(100) ,
  MATERIAL nvarchar(100) ,
  MEAS_UNITS nvarchar(100) ,
  MANU_FACT nvarchar(100) ,
  EC_CLASS_NAME nvarchar(100) ,
  WEIGHT_DRY float ,
  END_COND_1 nvarchar(100) ,
  PIPE_OD_M float ,
  PIPE_OD_R float ,
  END_COND_2 nvarchar(100) ,
  RUN_SIZE float ,
  MAIN_SIZE float ,
  MAT_GRADE nvarchar(100) ,
  SHORT_DESC nvarchar(100) ,
  LONG_DESCR nvarchar(100) ,
  WALL_THICKNESS_1 float ,
  PIECE_MARK nvarchar(100)
);
```

- [SQL Server Datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)

My suggestion would be to consider using an exact number datatype like `decimal` or `numeric`

Answer (score 1):

```
SCHEDULE double RATING nvarchar(100)
```

you forgot a comma after double.

Comment: Thanks...but also after adding the comma , I am getting the same error

Comment: I have no idea if the brackets([]) are affecting your code but try removing it, I haven't seen any create statements that has the table name inside brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: (You forget ',' after SCHEDULE double )

```
CREATE TABLE [PIPE]( ID double, REV nvarchar(100), SCHEDULE double, RATING nvarchar(100) , MATERIAL nvarchar(100) , MEAS_UNITS nvarchar(100) , MANU_FACT nvarchar(100) , EC_CLASS_NAME nvarchar(100) , WEIGHT_DRY double , END_COND_1 nvarchar(100) , PIPE_OD_M double , PIPE_OD_R double , END_COND_2 nvarchar(100) , RUN_SIZE double , MAIN_SIZE double , MAT_GRADE nvarchar(100) , SHORT_DESC nvarchar(100) , LONG_DESCR nvarchar(100) , WALL_THICKNESS_1 double , PIECE_MARK nvarchar(100));
```

also change double to float

```
CREATE TABLE PIPE
    ( 
    ID int,
    REV nvarchar(100),
    SCHEDULE1 float,
    RATING nvarchar(100),
    MATERIAL nvarchar(100),
    MEAS_UNITS nvarchar(100),
    MANU_FACT nvarchar(100),
    EC_CLASS_NAME nvarchar(100),
    WEIGHT_DRY float, 
    END_COND_1 nvarchar(100),
    PIPE_OD_M float,
    PIPE_OD_R float, 
    END_COND_2 nvarchar(100),
    RUN_SIZE float,
    MAIN_SIZE float,
    MAT_GRADE nvarchar(100),
    SHORT_DESC nvarchar(100),
    LONG_DESCR nvarchar(100),
    WALL_THICKNESS_1 float, 
    PIECE_MARK nvarchar(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the  comma between the fields , Check this out  [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7517).

Comment: Square brackets are used in SQL Server, also your SQL Fiddle demo is using MySQL as the DB but this question is tagged with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[PIPE] 
(
        ID DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   REV NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   SCHEDULE DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   RATING NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   MATERIAL NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   MEAS_UNITS NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   MANU_FACT NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   EC_CLASS_NAME NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   WEIGHT_DRY DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   END_COND_1 NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   PIPE_OD_M DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   PIPE_OD_R DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   END_COND_2 NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   RUN_SIZE DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   MAIN_SIZE DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   MAT_GRADE NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   SHORT_DESC NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   LONG_DESCR NVARCHAR(100)
    ,   WALL_THICKNESS_1 DECIMAL(18,2)
    ,   PIECE_MARK NVARCHAR(100)
);
```